# impropial integral and contraction with the comparation criteria

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to show that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$ is convergent. It's obvious because we can do the integral, but I have a dude with the comparation criteria. If I compare (by limit) with the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, we obtain:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1.
\end{equation*}
Then, $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty}g(x)dx$ have the same nature. Like $\int_0^{\infty}g(x)dx$ is divergent, then $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is also divergent. And this is a contradiction because the integral is convergent!! What am I doing bad?

Comment: Continuity is required, I believe.

Comment: $1/x^2$ is $\infty$  at $x=0$

Comment: Notice $\int_0^\infty = \int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty$.  We can use one bound on $[0,1]$ and another bound on $[1,\infty)$.  Your "$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)/g(x) = 1$" tells you about the $[1,\infty]$ integral.  It tells you nothing about the $[0,1]$ integral.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't apply the theorem because the integral of $g$ is both first and second species? And not only one

Answer (score 1):

The [comparison test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx) says that

If
$f(x)\ge g(x)\ge 0$

on the interval
$[a,\infty)$
then,

If $\int_a^\infty g(x) dx$ diverges then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx $ diverges.

The condition is not satisfied for your function because $\frac{1}{x^2}\gg \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ for $x\approx 0$. If you want to use the limit test, then both functions $f,g$ are required to be continuous on $[a,\infty)$ which is not true here: $\frac1{x^2}$ is not continuous on $[0,\infty)$.It is not even defined at $x=0$.